# Hierarchy navigation back button

Tags: c#, asp.net, navigation, hierarchy, back

I need to implement a back button for my asp application.

In my web application I got 3 module

1. task1.aspx ->task1-1.aspx ->task1-2.aspx
2. task2.aspx-> task2-1.aspx->task3-1.aspx
3. task3.aspx->task3-1.aspx->task2.1aspx

In the above example.3 module also can navigate to other pages . So now I got problem, is it possible to implement a back button based on which previous page that I come from.
For example, I click

task3.aspx -> task3-1.aspx -> task2.1aspx

then when I click back button, will be

task2.1aspx -> task3-1.aspx -> task3.aspx.

On the other hand, when  I click task2.aspx -> task2-1.aspx.

the back button will navigate me to task2-1.aspx ->task2.apx

Is it possible done in server side?

Answer (score 0):

You can do this way:

```
static string prevPage = String.Empty;

protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
     if( !IsPostBack )
     {
         prevPage = Request.UrlReferrer.ToString();
     }

 }

 protected void Button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
 {
      Response.Redirect(prevPage);
 }
```

For Multi-source cross page posting, it is suggested to use

```
<%@ PreviousPageType TypeName
```

instead of

```
<%@ PreviousPageType VirtualPath
```

Comment: This would not allow "backs" over multiple pages.

Comment: sorry. I try before. It will cause error. For example. task3.aspx -> task3-1.aspx -> task2.1aspx. then when I click back 2.1aspx ->task3-1.aspx. It cant go back to task3.aspx. It will navigate me go back to task3-1.aspx

Answer (score 0):

I would use use a [Stack](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.collections.stack%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) for this, and keep it in the [Session](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.httpcontext.session.aspx).  On each page load, push the current URL to the stack.

```
void Page_Init()
{
    Stack<string> history = Session["history"]; 
    if (history == null) history = new Stack<string>();
    history.Push(Request.Url.AbsoluteUri);
    Session["history"] = history;
}
```

Then of course in the click handler:

```
void Back_Click()
{
    Stack<string> history = Session["history"]; 
    if (history != null) 
    {
        string url = history.Pop();
        Session["history"] = history;
        Response.Redirect(url);
    }
}
```

Comment: This works partially. It would not work if you e.g. have multiple different windows open in the same session.

Comment: I just added an answer on how I do it :-)

Comment: thanks. Still got a better solution?Multiple tab will cause session problem

Answer (score 0):

I'm doing it in a somewhat similar way than [dbaseman explains](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12614173/107625).

Basically, I append a `BackUrl` query string parameter to each URL I'm redirecting the client to and to each link that a user potentially may click. This `BackUrl` parameter contains the *full* URL of the current page (including all parameters).

So you end up of a string getting longer and longer on each subsequent redirect or link being clicked by the user. Some time, the URL get's way too long.

My solution is to not store the actual URL to go back in the `BackUrl` query string parameter but just a hash code. Server-side, I have a string dictionary (in the user's session) to remember the hash codes and the actual URLs.

On the clicking of any "back" button in my website, I do a lookup inside this dictionary and then redirect to the matching URL found in the dictionary for the given hash.

The drawback of this aproach could be that the dictionary may grow over time and never shrinks. In all of my real-world projects that was never an issue, though. Plus, it gets released if the session is discared.

**So an example would be:**

- In `task1.aspx`, do not redirect user to `task1-1.aspx`, but to `task1-1.aspx?BackUrl=24378`.
- Store a server-side dictionary entry, mapping `24378` to `task1-1.aspx`.
- In `task1-1.aspx?BackUrl=24378`, do not redirect user to `task1-2.aspx`, but to `task1-2.aspx?BackUrl=93748`.
- Store a server-side dictionary entry, mapping `93748` to `task1-1.aspx?BackUrl=24378`.
- etc.

Then you can have a back button on your page.

- If the user clicks that back button, it calls to your `void BackButton_Click` function.
- In that function, use `Request["BackUrl"]` to get the hash code (e.g. `24378`).
- Use the hash code to look into the dictionary and get the actual URL.
- `Response.Redirect` to that URL.

That's basically the idea.

**Pseudo code:**

Some pseudo code to make it more clear.

For the dictionary, I would write me a helper property inside a `Page`-derived base class, like e.g.

```
protected Dictionary<string, string> BackUrls
{
    get
    {
        var dic = Session["backdic"] as Dictionary<string, string>;
        if ( dic == null )
        {
            dic = new Dictionary<string, string>();
        }
        return dic;
    }
}
```

You then can access the dictionary by writing to it or reading from it.

E.g. writing to dictionary:

```
private void goForwardToNextTask()
{
    var hash = Math.Abs(Guid.NewGuid().GetHashCode());

    // Store current page's full URL.
    BackUrls[hash] = Request.RawUrl;

    Response.Redirect( "task1-2.aspx?BackUrl=" + hash );
}
```

And reading from dictionary:

```
private void goBackward()
{
    var hash = Request["BackUrl"];

    // Backward translation.
    Response.Redirect( BackUrls[hash] );
}
```

(All examples omit error and sanity checking).

Comment: sorry. can guild me some example?

Comment: hi, still got a question. let say user now in task1-2.aspx ,he come from task1.aspx ->task1-1.aspx ->task1-2.aspx.  so when he click back button he should redirect to task1-1.aspx , then click back again . it will go back to task1.aspx. So how should I assign for the query string parameter?

Comment: @user998405 Actually, I think I have explained this in my answer. Each dictionary entry holds an URL with the hash code of another dictionary entry in the `BackUrl` parameter. This can be nested arbitrarily.

Comment: sorry. I still very fresh for aspx. Not very know about dictionary entry. I try first. Thanks :)